# How to add translation to CustomerAdressForm.php Prestashop 1.7.5

Tags: php, symfony, prestashop

added this chunk of code to validate() function in CustomerAdressForm.php file.

```
$nameField = $this->getField('phone');
        if((strlen($nameField->getValue())) < 7 ){
            $nameField->addError($this->translator->trans(
                "Not enough characters!", array(), 'Shop.Notifications.Error'
            ));
        }
```

The problem is, I can't find this string "Not enough characters!" in BO translations.

Answer (score 0):

Into Prestashop 1.7, the translation file is here : 
yourPrestashopFolder/app/Resources/translations/default

The third parameter for function trans give you a translation file : ShopNotificationsError.xlf

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) Can I ask you how this file works? To set translation for my file I just add rule to this xml file? Everything in this file is clear exept <trans-unit id="098eb45965b4097a844451b00737e89b"> From where should I get this trans-unit id?

Comment: Hello here a documentation with example xml https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/translation.html#basic-translation